# call method in controller with parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass parameters to the controller, In the below I have mention a brief explanation with the code,

**Controller**

```
class Site2 extends CI_Controller
{

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home()
    {
        $this->load->model('get_company_model');
        $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
        $data['results'] = $this->get_company_model->get_All();
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $this->load->view('view_nav',$data);
        $this->load->view('view_content');
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
    }
```

in the results array there are id and name,I can get these values in my view, then I need to pass id as parameters and call the function in controller.

**view**

```
<?php
    foreach($results as $row){

   echo $row->id;
    //I need to pass this particular id to the function

  }?>
```

Comment: wht you want to do after calling function in controller?. Do you want to process some code and want to dispaly on same view?

Comment: process some code and send data to the view

Comment: if you want to load data in same view without loading page than better use a function in model instead of controller.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:
1) If in same controller:

```
function home(){
    $this->load->model('get_company_model');
    $this->load->model('bank_account_model');
    $data['results'] = $this->get_company_model->get_All();
    $this->some_other_fn_in_same_controller( $data['results'] );
    $this->load->view('view_header');
    $this->load->view('view_nav',$data);
    $this->load->view('view_content');
    $this->load->view('view_footer');
}

function some_other_fn_in_same_controller( $results ){
    //to do
}
```

2) If from view:

2.1) Link:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>controller/function/$results['id']">Some Link</a>
```

2.2) Form: Just put the id in a hidden field and post the form to the controller and get the id in the controller as usual:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $result['id'] ?>">
$id = $this->input->post('id')
```

Comment: in my view there is a particular id inside  a loop I need to pass that articular id to the function in controller

Comment: Inside your foreach loop place the `<a>` tag